# Promise gets rejected even though there is no error. NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bluebird

So, I have a piece of code that makes use of `Promises` and I am using the `bluebird` library.

The problem is that my promise gets rejected even if there is no error. It completely skips the `.then` block even for a simple `console.log`

Here is the code that makes use of promise:

```
function returnMeetings(query) {
  return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
    Meeting.find(query, (err, foundMeetings) => {
      if (err) {
           console.log("We have a error")
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(foundMeetings);
    })
  })
}
```

And here is the code that makes use of that `returnMeetings` function

```
returnMeetings(query)
    .then((data) => {
    console.log("here we are")
    // while (count < stopAt) {
    //   let localData = [];
    //   if (req.params.duration === 'monthly') {
    //     let {
    //       date1,
    //       date2
    //     } = twoDates(count, count);
    //     localData = data.filter((el) => {
    //       if (el.startDate) {
    //         let localDate = new Date(el.startDate);
    //         if (localDate >= date1 && localDate <= date2) {
    //           return el;
    //         }
    //       }
    //     })
    //     if (localData) {
    //       data.push({
    //         data: localData,
    //         month: count
    //       })
    //     }
    //
    //     if (count === stopAt - 1) {
    //       myEmitter.emit('found all meetings')
    //     } else {
    //       count++;
    //     }
    //   }
    // }
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: err
    })
  })
```

As you can see in the `returnMeetings` function i have placed a `console.log` inside the `if(err)` block, and it never runs, from that I conclude that I didn't receive any error from the mongoose query.

Still, the code completely skips the `.then` block, and falls into the `catch` chain. I have a simple `console.log` inside the `then` block, and an interesting thing to note is that the value of `err` in the callback inside `catch` block is an array of mongodb documents.

Can someone explain, why is my code behaving in this manner?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe Meeting.find() throws an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the order of resolve/reject in your Promise constructor callback is wrong ... the names of the functions are irrelevant, the first is to resolve, the second is to reject ... you are actually rejecting the promise when you call `resolve`

i.e. you could

```
  return new Promise((fred, wilma) => {
```

then to resolve the promise, you would call `fred(value)` and to reject you would call `wilma(error)`

in other words, the names you give the callback arguments is irrelevant, the position is relevant

change your code as follows:

```
function returnMeetings(query) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Meeting.find(query, (err, foundMeetings) => {
      if (err) {
           console.log("We have a error")
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(foundMeetings);
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel so stupid. I thought of it to be an error first callback.